# Terminating blocking thread that has been deferredToThread

Tags: python, twisted

How can I modify this code (that uses twisted) so that CTRL+C will cause it to exit? I expect the problem is that `doWork` does not yield control back to the reactor, so the reactor is not able to terminate its execution.

```
def loop_forever():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
        time.sleep(5)

def doWork():
    for i in loop_forever():
        print i

def main():
    threads.deferToThread(doWork)
    reactor.run()
```

Note that this code:

```
def main():
    try:
        threads.deferToThread(doWork)
        reactor.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "user interrupted task"
```

does catch the exception on windows, but not on ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted uses Python's threading library to implement `deferToThread`.  All of the rules that apply to Python threads apply to the threads you get with `deferToThread`.  One rule is that signals and threads are a bad combination (Ctrl-C sends SIGINT on Linux).

The basic idea for solving this problem is to put some logic into `doWork` so that it will stop.  Perhaps this means setting a global flag that it checks once per iteration.  You can probably find lots of information elsewhere regarding strategies for getting a long-running thread to cooperate with shutdown.

You may also want to *not* use `deferToThread` for this.  If you expect your job to run for most of the lifetime of the process then you may just want to use the stdlib `threading` module directly.  Consider that a job like this is using up one of the thread pool slots.  If you have enough of these then your thread pool will be full and other work will not be able to proceed.

You may also want to take `doWork` *out* of the thread.  It doesn't look like it does a lot of blocking.  Instead, run `doWork` in the reactor thread and only run iterations of `loop_forever` with `deferToThread`.  Now you no longer have a long-running operation in a thread and several of your problems will probably go away.

Comment: In my real use case, the sleep command is actually a blocking wait on a serial port (using the python-xbee library), but I can still see defering to thread for each iteration. I will investigate.

Comment: Or take a look at `twisted.internet.serial` for non-threaded, natively-asynchronous serial port support. :)